# How to devide a shape file into two parts using python

Tags: python, split, geopandas, shapefile

I've got a shape file, as shown image.

[image]

I want to split it into two different shapefile, as shown in the second image.
[image]

How can I achieve this using python?

What I have tried so far is shown below.

```
import geopandas as gpd ; import shapefile ; import numpy as np ; import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ;  

lat_1=6 ; lat_2=20 ; lon_1=70 ; lon_2=90
A=gpd.read_file(shp_file)
points=[]
for shape_rec in A.shapeRecords():
    #print(shape_rec)
     pts = pd.DataFrame(np.array(shape_rec.shape.points))
     pts.columns=['lon','lat']
     points.append(pts) 
points_1=pd.concat(points)

points_2=points_1[(points_1.lon >=lon_1)&(points_1.lon <=lon_2) & (points_1.lat >=lat_1)&(points_1.lat <=lat_2)] 


gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame( points_2, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(points_2.lon , points_2.lat ), crs='EPSG:4326')
gdf.drop(['lat', 'lon'], axis=1, inplace=True)  # optional
gdf.to_file(main+'shp_files/test.shp')
```

This is giving the output as line of multiple points
Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Shapely has a function to split a polygon by a line: [shapely.ops.split(geom, splitter)](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.split).

Because geopandas geometries are actually stored as shapely objects under the hood you can quite easily use shapely operations on them. Some more information and examples can be found [in the geopandas user guide](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/geometric_manipulations.html).